# Predict Longitude and Latitude time series

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, python, spatial

I have a dataset that describes location (latitude longitude) in different times of day. The dataset is for one day and has 10 minute intervals (so 144 observations).
I need to predict the location at some specific point in time in the future.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other predictors? A neural network with 2 output neurons might be a way forward.

Comment: No other predictors

Comment: I am guessing then that all you will retrieve is the mean of lat / lon with no other predictors.